# Why does this VLOOKUP result in an #N/A error?

Tags: excel, vlookup

Here is a simplified version. I was trying to match the shop grade from a given table to the data but it returned error, what's wrong with my vlookup function? I'm an Excel beginner.

The data:

[image: The data]

The given table:

[image: The given table]

Comment: Is the last parameter in your `VLOOKUP()` a ***zero*** ??

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to match Column B so your lookup range should start with that:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Table!B2:C3,2,False)
```

Vlookup requires the first column to be the lookup column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look up by referencing the first column in the table. In this case, change B2 to A2 and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**What is vlookup?**
Does a lookup for a specified value in the left most column of a specified table(table_array) vertically from top to bottom and returns a value from one of the columns(column_index_number) of the table. Formula follows

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,column_index_number,[range_lookup])
```

**These are common pitfalls with vlookup.**

If table A is used to lookup and table B is getting populated with values

- Lookup value is not first column of table array(table A)
- Lookup column on table array is not sorted - sort using excel sort function in Data tab
- Dragging the formula would have caused Table array to shift for each lookup in table B. E.g `A1:C10` may become `A2:C11` for second lookup and can result in #NA if lookup result falls in top rows which is missing. Use `$A$1:$C$10` as lookup array table A to make sure that formula is not affected while dragging the cells. Alternately, naming table array can also be employed.
- Range lookup true can result in getting invalid results even when no result is present in table A. Using range lookup false will be accurate in most cases.

Reference :

[MS Office vlookup help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60150&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[Named tables in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4D0F13AC-53B7-422E-AFD2-ABD7FF379C64)